# Jquery call on datalist tab or enter on an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a function to execute when someone enters a four to five digit number in a specific input field.

Here is my code:

```
$('body').on('keyup click','input[name=id]',function(){
    if($(this).val().length>3){
        console.log('Hello');
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is that `input[name=id]` has a `datalist` for helping in select known ids. So when someone types in all four digits like 3043 the function above will execute. If someone types 30 and then arrows down to the datalist option 3043 and presses enter it will execute.

BUT

If anyone types 30 and then arrows down to 3043 and presses TAB it will not execute. If anyone types 30 and then clicks on the datalist option 3043 it will not execute.

I need it to be able to catch all four possible actions.

Comment: add change to the jQuery .on call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the 'input' event. Which is exactly what you want. The input event is supported by all browser, but datalist isn't either (all browsers which support datalist also support input event).

```
$('#id').on('input',function(){
    if($(this).val().length>3){
        console.log('Hello');
    }
});
```